# How do I convert UTC date into user timezone in fullCalendar.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, timezone, fullcalendar, momentjs

I have a date and time in UTC format such as :

[image: event start and end time]

My calendar generating code. I am using [fullcalendar.io](https://fullcalendar.io/).

```
//for loop start
sessionCalendar.push(
    {
      title: `${course["course_name"]}`,
      start: start_date_time.split(" ").join("T"),
      end: end_date_time.split(" ").join("T"),
    },
)
//for loops end
```

As you can see I have added `T` in the middle of date and time to make it UTC format.

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  plugins: [ 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'interaction' ],
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
  },
  defaultDate: '2019-04-12',
  navLinks: true, 
  editable: false,
  eventLimit: true,
  events: sessionCalendar,
  timeZone: timeZone // var timeZone = "Asia/Kolkata"
});

calendar.render();
```

In the above code, I have set the timeZone value which is dynamic. Still, I see the same date and time as `start_date_time` in the screenshot which is UTC format.

How do I convert UTC date and time into user-specified timezone?

As per comment. I added "Z" at the end

[image: UTC timezone]

Comment: Try also adding a 'Z' at the end to have the date parse as UTC as well. `new Date( '2019-05-08T11:18:00' ) !== new Date( '2019-05-08T11:18:00Z' );`. Then you can get the local datetime from that Date object.

Comment: I added but no change. The calendar is still showing the same date and time.

Comment: Guess you'll have to dive deep into the fullcalendar docs to find the correct way the library expects you to set timezones. :/

Comment: Yea I was reading docs aswell, at the same I posted here if any body knows what is wrong. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Just for my understanding why do you do `start_date_time.split(" ").join("T")`?

Comment: My default date format is "2019-05-22 10:18:00" in order to make it UTC validated I need to separate by space. and join by T. Also we need to add Z at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem but not genuinely.

Before calling initialize calendar I convert the date and time to user-specific timezone.

```
datetime_utc: function (datetime) {
    return moment.utc(datetime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').clone().tz(timeZone).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
},
```

The above moemnt function easily converting the date and time to user-specific timezone. I just updated the time. Also I remove the timezone properties from can calendar function.

```
//for loop start
sessionCalendar.push(
    {
      title: `${course["course_name"]}`,
      start: gbl.datetime_utc(start_date_time),
      end: gbl.datetime_utc(end_date_time),
    },
)
//for loops end

var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  plugins: [ 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'interaction' ],
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
  },
  defaultDate: '2019-04-12',
  navLinks: true, 
  editable: false,
  eventLimit: true,
  events: sessionCalendar,
});

calendar.render();
```

Still this is very incomplete answer. Fullcalendar.io code should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

function convertDateAccordingToTZ(dateString: string, timeZoneOffset: number = 0) {

```
const dateObj = new Date(dateString);
const calculatedOffset = dateObj.getTimezoneOffset() + (timeZoneOffset * 60);
const formattedTime = dateObj.valueOf() + (calculatedOffset * 60000);

return new Date(formattedTime);
```

}

Comment: Can you improve my answer? Because I know how to convert a UTC date into user-specific timezone. I have done that via moment.js and it is working fine. Here I need to specify the timezone with UTC date time and it should convert automatically. But it is not happening.

Comment: I think we should not add `z` to assume it as UTC date, it should come from server side.

Comment: You are right, you can assign `z` at your side also, try to pass my functions converted date to calender